# How to download the folders from gcs bucket to local using python?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bucket

I have a model and other folders in the gcs bucket where I need to download into my local. I have the service account of that gcs bucket as well.

**gs bucket: gs://test_bucket/11100/e324vn241c9e4c4/artifacts**

Below is the code I am using to download the folder

```
from google.cloud import storage
storage_client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json(
    'service_account.json')
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
blobs_all = list(bucket.list_blobs())
blobs = bucket.list_blobs(prefix='artifacts')
for blob in blobs:
   if not blob.name.endswith('/'):
      print(f'Downloading file [{blob.name}]')
      blob.download_to_filename(f'./{blob.name}')
```

The above code is not working properly. I want to download all the folders that are saved in the artifacts folder (confusion_matrix, model and roc_auc_plot) in google bucket. Below images shows the folders

[image]

Can anyone tell me how to download those folders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `prefix='artifacts'` part will not work.

What you need is:

```
blobs = [b for b in blobs_all if b.id.__contains__('artifacts/')]
```

Additionally, the `download_to_filename` call will probably fail if the folder structure does not exist yet. Something like `blob.download_to_filename(f'./{blob.name.replace("/","-")}')` should work though.